# Unable to configure NGINX to using custom installed openssl

Tags: nginx, openssl, fips

Trying to configure nginx with the custom openssl in the alpine base image, but it does seem to pick the openssl which is placed under `/usr/local/openssl`

```
Step 20/22 : RUN cd nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}/ &&     ./configure ${NGINX_FLAGS} &&     make &&     sudo make install
 ---> Running in 58c8b603c0b7

    
    checking for getaddrinfo() ... found
    checking for PCRE library ... found
    checking for PCRE JIT support ... found
    checking for OpenSSL library ... not found
    checking for OpenSSL library in /usr/local/ ... not found
    checking for OpenSSL library in /usr/pkg/ ... not found
    checking for OpenSSL library in /opt/local/ ... not found
    
    ./configure: error: SSL modules require the OpenSSL library.
    You can either do not enable the modules, or install the OpenSSL library
    into the system, or build the OpenSSL library statically from the source
    with nginx by using --with-openssl=<path> option.
```

If i end up using the `--with-openssl` flag i need to pass the source for the openssl, which is we do not have.

I am trying to configure nginx to be fips enabled, thus configuring nginx manually to pick the openssl library we have built, any workaround/help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Inspect the `configure.log` file or `configure` itself to see how exactly it checks for the OpenSSL library - maybe you are missing an export symbol or a proper symlink or a conf file inside `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` As a last resort - you can put the OpenSSL sources next to nginX sources and use that `--with-openssl` option. At least I do it in this way (although I am not on Alpine)

Comment: Thanks @IVOGELOV, will check them out!